# How can I fix this parralax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

This is my first time working with a Parallax type thing in jQuery...
And I have come to a breaking point and I don't know how to fix it.

[Click here for JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tMmnh/5/)

My code is... 
HTML

`<div id="bannerText" style="margin-top: 0px; opacity: 1;">
    <center>Text, blah blah blah</center>
    </div>`

Javascript

```
 function scrollBanner() {
//Get the scoll position of the page
scrollPos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

//Scroll and fade out the banner text
jQuery('#bannerText').css({
  'margin-top' : -(scrollPos/3)+"px",
  'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/300)
});
 }
```

CSS

`#bannerText {
    position: fixed;
    top: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}`

I'm trying to make it so when the user scrolls down, the text comes down slowly with them (but slower than them, so it goes off screen) and have it fade out.

Right now, it does well, nothing.  It just has my text on the screen...

EDIT: [trying to make it somewhat like this websites, for example, Click here](http://themetrust.com/demos/hero/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example

You can play with the parameters to get the effect you want.  Be sure to include jQuery in your page too as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/tMmnh/6/):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    //Get the scoll position of the page
    scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    //Scroll and fade out the banner text
    $('#bannerText').css({
      'margin-top' : (scrollPos/3)+"px",
      'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/100)
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/atiDaGA/2/)

```
     function scrollBanner() {
    //Get the scoll position of the page
    scrollPos = jQuery(this).scrollTop();

    //Scroll and fade out the banner text
    jQuery('#txt').css({
      'margin-top' : -(scrollPos/3)+"px",
      'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/500)
    });
     }

$(document).scroll(function(){
scrollBanner();

});
```

**HTML**

```
  <div id="bannerText" style="margin-top: 0px; opacity: 1;">
    <center><h1 id='txt'>Text, blah blah blah</h1></center>
</div>

<div id="expander"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#bannerText {
position: fixed;
top: 250px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
  height:300px;
  background:orange;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#expander{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:30000px;

}
#txt{
position:fixed;
  top:500px;
}
```